# Kivy: Object motion/updating issue (Kivy Pong tutorial adaptation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have adapted a part of the kivy pong tutorial (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html) to create a ball class that should update 60 times a second, moving the ball around the screen. Similarly, when the ball hits the sides, it should be reflected in the opposite direction. However the ball just sits in the corner of the screen motionless. What is the syntax/logic error that I'm making?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition,\
SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from random import randint

Builder.load_string('''
<Ball>:
    Image:
        source: '58-Breakout-Tiles.png'
        size: 15, 15
        pos: self.pos



<SettingsScreen>:
    close: close
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: close
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'grey_crossGrey.png'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            font_name: 'vgafix.fon'
            text: 'Music: '
        Switch:
            active: True
        Label:
            font_name: 'vgafix.fon'
            text: 'Sounds: '
        Switch:
            active: True

<MenuScreen>:
    cog: cog
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: cog
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'settings-cog.png'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            source: 'brickbreaker log.png'
        Label:
            font_name: 'vgafix.fon'
            text: 'Tap to start'

<GameScreen>:
    ball: ball
    cog: cog
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Image:
            id: cog
            size_hint: .03, .03
            source: 'settings-cog.png'

    Ball:
        id: ball
        center: self.parent.center
''')

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')



class Ball(Widget):
    velocityX, velocityY = NumericProperty(0), NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocityX, velocityY)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class Player(Widget):
    pass

class Brick(Widget):
    pass




class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.previous = False

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.close.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            sm.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'right')
            sm.current = self.previous

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.cog.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            sm.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'left')
            sm.get_screen('settings').previous = 'menu'
            sm.current = 'settings'
        else:
            sm.transition = FadeTransition()
            sm.current = 'game'

class GameScreen(Screen):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initBall()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.cog.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            sm.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'left')
            sm.get_screen('settings').previous = 'game'
            sm.current = 'settings'

    def initBall(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocityY *= -1
        # bounce off left and right
        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.velocityX *= -1

sm = ScreenManager(transition = FadeTransition())
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='game'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))



class BrickBreakerInsanityApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(sm.get_screen('game').update, 1.0/60.0)
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BrickBreakerInsanityApp().run()
```

**code assets:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR799.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYvL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuxI3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypd7C.png

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GAnv5DfjNUuAXTybmsan90Dm0OuSVOfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to the problem.

## Method 1 - kv file

- Remove `Image:`
- Add `size_hint: None, None` to overwrite the default size of (1, 1) or (100, 100)
- Add `canvas:`

### Snippets

```
Builder.load_string('''
<Ball>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 15, 15
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: '58-Breakout-Tiles.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

### [Kivy Canvas » source](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.source)

> ```
> source
> ```
>
> This property represents the filename to load the texture from. If you
>   want to use an image as source, do it like this:
>
> ```
> with self.canvas:
>     Rectangle(source='mylogo.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
> ```
>
> Here’s the equivalent in Kivy language:
>
> ```
> <MyWidget>:
>     canvas:
>         Rectangle:
>             source: 'mylogo.png'
>             pos: self.pos
>             size: self.size
> ```

## Method 2 - kv & py files

- Move ball definitions from kv file into Python script
- Create a texture of the ball image
- Declare a rectangle containing the ball's texture to the canvas
- Bind the rectangle, `self.rect` to a method, `update_ball()` whenever there is a `pos` or `size` changes.

### Snippets - py

```
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
...
class Ball(Widget):
    velocityX, velocityY = NumericProperty(0), NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocityX, velocityY)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Ball, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        texture = Image('58-Breakout-Tiles.png').texture
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.size = (15, 15)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_ball, size=self.update_ball)

    def update_ball(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
```

### Snippets - kv

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SettingsScreen>:
```

### [Kivy Canvas » texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.texture)

> ```
> texture
> ```
>
> Property that represents the texture used for drawing this
>   Instruction. You can set a new texture like this:
>
> ```
> from kivy.core.image import Image
>
> texture = Image('logo.png').texture
> with self.canvas:
>     Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
> ```
>
> Usually, you will use the source attribute instead of the texture.

Comment: out of interest, what is the benefit of creating a rect for each object instead of moving the image directly? i do this in pygame to manipulate game objects - does the same usage apply?

Comment: There are two solutions to the problem. I just updated my post with an alternate solution similar to pygame i.e. manipulating game objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly working. A fairly simple fix is to just change your `Ball` to extend `Image` (instead of `Widget`), and add `size_hint: None, None`.

So, the `Ball` class declaration becomes:

```
class Ball(Image):
```

The class itself can remain the same

The rule for the `Ball` in your `kv` file is simplified to:

```
<Ball>:
    source: '58-Breakout-Tiles.png'
```

And in your `GameScreen` rule, the `Ball` section becomes:

```
Ball:
    id: ball
    size_hint: None, None
    center: self.parent.center
```

Just adding the `size_hint`.

I think that is enough to get it working.

Alternatively, you can just add the `size_hint` to your `Ball` as:

```
Ball:
    id: ball
    size_hint: None, None
    center: self.parent.center
```

and change `pos: self.pos` to `pos: root.pos` in your `<Ball>:` rule as:

```
<Ball>:
    Image:
        source: '58-Breakout-Tiles.png'
        size: 15, 15
        pos: root.pos
```

The main problem with your original code is that adding an `Image` to a `Widget` is just adding a child to the `Ball` `Widget`. A `Widget` that is not a `Layout` does not handle drawing its children. The original `Pong` game gets around this by putting the ball image in the `Canvas` of the `Ball` `Widget`. The `Image` class basically does that for you.

Comment: ah I see, that makes a lot of sense - having the ball as an Image object rather than a Widget containing an image is a more logical approach if it needs to be constantly updated. thanks!